# Assign a value to a final variable

Tags: java, callback, final

Suppose I have this code:

```
public HttpResponse myFunction(...) {
    final HttpResponse resp;
    OnResponseCallback myCallback = new OnResponseCallback() {
        public void onResponseReceived(HttpResponse response) {
            resp = response;
        }
    };
    // launch operation, result will be returned to myCallback.onResponseReceived()
    // wait on a CountDownLatch until operation is finished
    return resp;
}
```

Obviously I can not assign a value to resp from onResponseReceived because it is a final variable, BUT if it was not a final variable onResponseReceived could not see it.
Then, how can I assign a value to resp from onResponseReceived?

What I thought is to create a wrapper class for enclosing the resp object. The final object would be an instance of this wrapper class and I could assign the value to resp working on the object inside the final class (which is not final).

The code would be this one:

```
class ResponseWrapper {
    HttpResponse resp = null;
}

public HttpResponse myFunction(...) {
    final ResponseWrapper respWrap = new ResponseWrapper();
    OnResponseCallback myCallback = new OnResponseCallback() {
        public void onResponseReceived(HttpResponse response) {
            respWrap.resp = response;
        }
    };
    // launch operation, result will be returned to myCallback.onResponseReceived()
    // wait on a CountDownLatch until operation is finished
    return respWrap.resp;
}
```

What do you think about this solution?

Comment: First of all, does it work? Have you tried it to see the result?

Comment: Yes it works, but I don 't know if this is a good way of solving this general problem.

Comment: Then, this is would probably be a better post for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html)

Standard practice is to use a final AtomicReference, which you can set and get. This adds the benefit of thread safety as well :) As you mentioned, a CountDownLatch is helpful in waiting for completion.

Comment: Thanks! This practice is surely better than mine :) thanks also to the others, all userful responses!

Answer (score 4):

Your solution is as valid as any other. Other popular choices include the one element array

```
final HttpResponse[] resp = new Response[1];
// In the callback
resp[0] = response;
// After the operation
return resp[0];
```

and the generic wrapper

```
public class Ref<T> {
  public T value;
}

final Ref<HttpResponse> resp;
// In the callback
resp.value = response;
// After the operation
return resp.value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the hand-back and the wait into one using a `SynchronousQueue` (exception handling omitted)

```
public HttpResponse myFunction(...) {
    final Queue<HttpResponse> resp = new SynchronousQueue<HttpResponse>();
    OnResponseCallback myCallback = new OnResponseCallback() {
        public void onResponseReceived(HttpResponse response) {
            resp.put(response);
        }
    };
    return resp.take();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The change I would make would be to use an [AtomicReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) since this is obviously multi-threaded and you wouldn't have to write your own wrapper. Otherwise, seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it mutable and final ;) The simplest approach is to use na array but an AtomicReference can also be used.

```
public HttpResponse myFunction(...) {
    final HttpResponse[] resp = { null };
    OnResponseCallback myCallback = new OnResponseCallback() {
        public void onResponseReceived(HttpResponse response) {
            resp[0] = response;
        }
    };
    // launch operation, result will be returned to myCallback.onResponseReceived()
    // wait on a CountDownLatch as soon as operation is finished
    return resp[0];
}
```

or

```
public HttpResponse myFunction(...) {
    final AtomicReference<HttpResponse> resp = new AtomicReference<HttpResponse>();
    OnResponseCallback myCallback = new OnResponseCallback() {
        public void onResponseReceived(HttpResponse response) {
            resp.set(response);
        }
    };
    // launch operation, result will be returned to myCallback.onResponseReceived()
    // wait on a CountDownLatch as soon as operation is finished
    return resp.get();
}
```